# server response for file upload to blue imp file upload

Tags: php, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

What is the format of the response of our php script to show result in the list of file uploads.

I am using bluImp jQuery Fileupload plugin and php to handle file upload. The files are uploaded and need to show either error message or file uploaded once the file upload is complete. I am not sure what is the format of the response of the script I have written to handle file upload to blueImp jQuery fileupload plugin.

Answer (score 4):

The data response format is the one you decide to use on the server side.

There is a [dataType option](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#wiki-datatype) you can use to transparency convert the response in your JavaScript code. Most of [documentation exemples](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#wiki-datatype) use Json format, which one I recommend.

Edit about error response :

PHP file :

```
return Response::json(array('success' => false, 'reason' => 'No file found',
                    'id' => $id));
```

JavaScript file :

```
done: function(){
    r = data.result;
    if (r.success) {
        $('#notice_' + r.id).replaceWith('<p class="notice success">...</p>');
    } else {
        $('#asset_' + r.id).replaceWith('<p class="notice error">r.reason</p>');
    }
```

Comment: I found the data format for returning success file upload. I am still not sure how I should format the return from my php script in case of file upload error. How should I format my error message?

Comment: @user2159787 The error message format is the same **if** you get an response from the server (otherwise you just get the error HTTP code with default error message). I edited my question with an example of how I do (into the *done* callback, that is to say without HTTP error code). Tell me if you have any questions.

Comment: @Fractaliste: can you please tell where to place this JS code , as at the moment i can figure out where i must place this JS code

Comment: @temp-learn See the first code example of [this page](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin) which have a `done` callback.